# Queuing outgoing packets to fix server lag issues

Tags: java, networking, libgdx, netty

I have been developing a game lately, my first multiplayer game. I am using [Netty](https://netty.io/) and [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).

So previously, before this update I added, I was only queuing incoming packets, I had to do this because  I did not want to process packets on the netty thread, and instead process them on the game logic thread. So I had to add the incoming `Packet` to a queue, and then every game service tick execute them.

Now, I was not queuing outgoing packets `server->client`, it will just instant `write and flush` no matter where. On localhost, it worked very well, but once it was live with a few players, my game was having big delays, and mostly disconnects because of timeouts.

After adding an outgoing packet queuing, if absolutely fixed the lag, example:

**`Player#sendPacket(OutgoingPacket p)`:**

```
/**
 * Sends a packet
 *
 * @param packet The packet to send
 */
public void sendPacket(OutgoingPacket packet) {
    packetQueue.add(packet);
}
```

This takes the outgoing packet that was constructed, and adds it to the outgoing packets queue, which is local in every `Player` object.

And then in my game service loop I have the following:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        context.getPackets().queuePackets(); // incoming packets
        context.getTimeMachine().tick();
        context.getPlayerManager().tick();
        context.getPlayerManager().queueOutgoingPackets(); // outgoing packets
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ServerContext.log(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And the following method `context.getPlayerManager().queueOutgoingPackets()`:

```
public void queueOutgoingPackets() {
    for (Player p : players) {
        p.queueOutgoingPackets();
    }
}
```

Which happens to do this for every player:

```
public void queueOutgoingPackets() {
    while(!packetQueue.isEmpty()) {
        packetQueue.poll().send(this);
    }
}
```

And simply send:

```
public void send(Player p) {
    encode();
    p.getChannel().writeAndFlush(this);
}
```

Now this fixed my lag issues, completely, I would really like to know, why and how did this affect my networking performance? Is that because write and flush slowing down Netty thread, so when I send packets casually in middle of the game logic?

Now someone told me that I have to limit the outgoing packets queue per tick, per player, in case of a packets spam that comes from a player, think that it makes sense to do so? *Should it also be done for incoming packets?*